# how to replace or redefine parent class' inline-component

Tags: qt, inheritance, qml

I would like to know if it is possible to replace/redefine a parent's inline component.  There are ways to do so with a 'classic' component; for example, I can assign the component to a property and re-define the property:

**Super.qml**

```js
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12

Rectangle {

    property Component classicComponent: Text { text: "Hello" }

    width: 60
    height: 30
    border.color: "blue"
    border.width: 2

    Loader {
        id: loader
        sourceComponent: classicComponent
    }
}
```

**main.qml**

```js
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12

Window {
    width: 80
    height: 90
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Column {
        x: 10; y: 10
        spacing: 10
        Super { }
        Super {
            classicComponent: Label {
                text: "World"
                background: Rectangle { color: "#30DD0000" }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Output from MRE]

I would like to know if it is possible to do something conceptually similar, but with an inline component.  I have not found any way to combine an inline component with a property, and if I try something like:

**InlineParent.qml**

```js
Rectangle {
    component Foo: Text { text: "Hello" }

    Foo {}
}
```

and

**Child.qml**

```js
InlineParent {
    component Foo: Label { 
        text: "World"
        background: Rectangle { color: "#30DD0000" }
    }
}
```

Both will print "Hello".  Obviously, there are better ways to add a red background to an Item (such as Text); the concept I am interested in is in having the subclass redefine a component declared in the superclass/parent class.

Comment: You could make the `classicComponent` property a [default property](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-objectattributes.html#defining-property-attributes) (not 100% sure if that works)

Comment: Hi @Amfasis, thanks for the suggestion. In my case, the default property is already engaged for another purpose - a better MRE from me would have helped making this clear. I will check this out anyway - it should come in handy in a similar case.

Answer (score 0):

After getting some sleep, I found that it IS possible to place an inline component in a property, allowing a subclass to redefine it or expand it.

**Super.qml**

```js
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12

Rectangle {

    property Component inlineComponent: Foo {}

    component Foo: Text { text: "Hello" }
    
    width: 60
    height: 30
    border.color: "blue"
    border.width: 2

    Loader {
        id: loader
        sourceComponent: inlineComponent
    }
}
```

**main.qml**

```js
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12

Window {
    width: 80
    height: 130
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Column {
        x: 10; y: 10
        spacing: 10
        Super { }
        Super {
            inlineComponent: Label {
                text: "World"
                background: Rectangle { color: "#30dd0000" }
            }
        }
        Super {
            inlineComponent: Super.Foo {
                text: "World"
                Rectangle {
                    color: "#30dd0000"
                    anchors.fill: parent
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It solved my problem, allowing me to replace or extend Foo.